# What is the most efficient (fastest) way to concatenate two large (over 1.5GB) files in java?

Tags: java, file, io, nio

I have utilized the techniques here and concatenated two 1.5GB files in 70 seconds.

http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly

My code involved using FileChannels with memory mapping and ByteBuffers with an 8KB buffer size.

How could I improve this speed?

```
File file = new File(binDirectory + "/donjon.avi");
File oFile = new File(binDirectory + "/donjon2.avi");

FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(oFile);
FileChannel f1 = is.getChannel();
FileChannel f2 = fos.getChannel();

f2.transferFrom(f1, 0, f1.size());
f2.transferFrom(f1, f1.size(), f1.size());

f2.close();
f1.close();
```

Comment: Play with your buffer size, it may/may not get faster.

Comment: A buffer of only 8kB? Try something in the range of 1MB to 10MB for such huge files.

Comment: If you know the platforms your Java app will run on, you could try using shell commands and take advantage of the platform-specific optimizations.

Comment: Is this Java question related to a Java application that is deployed on server (1 consumer) or a Java application deployed to Desktop (many consumers)? If this is application deployed on server wouldn't it be faster to call external command to concatenate two files? How about using command cat (in *nix like os's)? http://www.linfo.org/cat.html 
cat file1 file2 file3 > file4

Comment: It is a merely a question satisfying curiosities pertaining to limits within Java programming. Thank you for your comments, however, I do not wish to use external commands.

Comment: Open the first file for R/W, seek to the end, and append.

Comment: You are now transferring data at 20 MB/sec rate. Depending on drive you are using it may be limited by I/O speed, not Java. You can easily verify optimal speed by using `cat` to make concatenated file, see how long that takes.

Comment: Concatenating two `.avi`s may not result in expected results. There is extra data that you might not be considering for, just saying: [AVI File Format](http://www.alexander-noe.com/video/documentation/avi.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. They are test files that satisfy the large size requirement. Interesting document though!

Answer (score 13):

try this

```
    FileChannel c1 = new FileInputStream("1").getChannel();
    FileChannel c2 = new FileOutputStream("2", true).getChannel();
    c2.transferFrom(c1, c2.size(), c1.size());
```

javadoc says that `FileChannel.transferFrom` is potentially much more efficient than a simple loop that reads from this channel and writes to the target channel. Many operating systems can transfer bytes directly from the filesystem cache to the target channel without actually copying them.

Comment: Indeed it is faster for manually copying the bytes of a file to another. Thank you. I have tried to modify it to duplicate the contents of the first file within the output file unsuccessfully. My code is in my question.